# Mapping with Zed Camera

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, frames, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i want to use our Stereolabs Zed Cam to get a map in Rviz. I set up zed-wrapper (and SDK and Cuda) successfully and startet the zed.launch file to get image data. The data is broadcasted to its topics and i can get it echoing the corresponding topics. Also in rqt the images can be shown. But if i open rviz i can't see anything. No image data, no pointcloud,...
I loaded the rviz config file from stereolabs and the first different point on my system is: I have no map frame. There are only the following frames availabe: base_frame, base_link, odometry_frame, zed_camera_center, zed_{left,right}*camera*{optical}_frame.
I found out it could be a problem with this tricky fixed frame and got the tf-tree attached below. There i can find two subtrees... Is this correct or is this my problem? With frame base_link chosen the rviz looks as in the image below. TF says "No transform from [base_frame] to frame [base_link]. I think this is a problem, but why and how to solve it? [image: Nothing to see here][image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331367/mapping-with-zed-camera/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should remap the frame in either the zed_node or state publisher to have the same frame. Alternatively, you can add the base_frame to base_link transform to a robot state publisher.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dasmurat](https://answers.ros.org/users/107938/dasmurat/) on 2022-06-10**:
How to do that?